# laravel read a checkbox value in a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my **html blade** code

```
{{Form::checkbox('remember_me', '', array('id'=>'remember_id'))}}
        <label for="remember_id">Remember me</label>
```

This is my **controller** code:

```
 echo Input::get('remember_me');exit;
```

1. The result is always empty, why please?
2. The checkbox is always checked when I run the page, why please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look on the [parameter list of the `Form::checkbox()` method][1].

The second parameter is your checkbox value. You manually set it to an empty string. Set it to `null` in order to keep the browsers default values (laravel default is 1). The third parameter is a boolean. Set it to true to check the box and false to uncheck it.

The fourth parameter is your options array where you can specify your id. So the correct method call should be:

```
{{Form::checkbox('remember_me', null, false, array('id'=>'remember_id'))}}
```

**Update:**

Checkboxes that are not checked, will not be included in your POST data. So the only reliable way to verify that a checkbox has been checked is to check if it is set. That can be done using `isset()` with regular PHP functions, or if laravel is being used, by using `Input::has()` which returns a boolean dependent on whether your input data contains a given key.

Comment: when applying your code, the checkbox becomes unchecked, which is good, but the controller print nothing when the checkbox is unchecked and printed `null` when the checkbox is checked

Comment: Checkboxes that are not checked will not be send via POST, that's why you get `null` when it's unchecked and you cannot alter this behavior. That means you first need to check whether the checkbox has a value, and then check for the value. 

`null` should not be printed when you checked the box. Are you sure you did not put `null` in string literals?

Comment: when i removed the string literal arround the null, i got `on` when the checkbox is checked and nothing when it is not checked. so you mean that I need just to check if the form has the checkbox name. otherwise, the checkbox will not checked, right?

Comment: Right. As I said checkboxes that are not checked will not be sent via POST and so their value will be null. You can verify that by using `Input::has('remember_me')` in your controller. You should get null when the checkbox has not been checked and true otherwise

Answer (score 1):

You did not add a value to the checkbox

```
{{Form::checkbox('remember_me', 'value goes here', true, array('id'=>'remember_id'))}}
```

The second param is the value

Comment: I already tried to put `false` in the second value, but still the checkbox is checked and nothing printed in the controller

Comment: edited my answer, forgot that the third param is the checked state, try now

Comment: now when the checkbox is unchecked, the controller prints nothing, and when the checkbox is checked the controller prints `value goes here` . what i need is either `true/false` or `on/of`

Comment: Its normal, you will only get a value from a checkbox, when its checked, and where it says "value goes here" i just placed that there as an example, replace it with your value...

Comment: +1 to you, I wish I could accept more than answer. Many thanks for your great efforts

Answer (score 0):

Normally I write the checkbox without blade and I can do with it whatever I want, like normal HTML. I don't see why you can do it the normal HTML way, because it always ends up doing the same thing you expert.

Comment: +1 to your answer, I choose blade over html because I need to save the checkbox value when the page is redirected in case the authentication falls

Comment: Actually, you can do that with a normal checkbox, blade has nothing to with that, second, and no offense, blade generates a checkbox for you, and it helps you generate a cleaner html.

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::label('Test-2') !!} {!! Form::checkbox('ch[]', 'value-2', false); !!}
```